# Ansible Host: how to get the value for $HOME variable?

Tags: ansible

I know about `ansible_env.HOME` variable, which allow us to retrieve the path for the home user for the VMs we are connecting using Ansible.

However I need to get the home path for the ansible host. That means, the machine which is running the ansible playbook. Is there a short variable to retrieve that information? I was hoping to avoid running a local command and storing the result in a variable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to access it with a lookup plugin like so:

```
- debug: msg="{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}"
```

Lookup plugins run on the control machine not the remote systems.

Comment: Great! I was confused and though lookup and ansible_env were the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: And guess what, `HOME` variable is not defined on any platform.

Comment: @Vini.g.fer `lookup` gives you the env vars  of the local computer which is running the Ansible script. `ansible_env` gives you the variables in the remote machine